# Updating array mapped via the knockout mapping plugin replaces the contents of the array

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an object in my view model that gets updated with array data from the server using the mapping plugin.

Contents of the mapped observable array are displayed in a table. Now, the user has the capability to 'load more', which triggers a request to the server and gets the next 
'n' rows of data from the server.

Updating the view model object using the mapping plugin with new data causes the existing data to be replaced. My goal is to make the mapping plugin append the new data to the existing observable array.

Wondering if this is possible using a custom 'create' or an 'update' callback? If yes, some examples would really help.

For now, as a workaround - I've resorted to manually pushing data into the view model object.

Comment: The mapping plugin is designed to handle additional data, so it is perfectly fine if you manually pushing your data....

Answer (score 0):

you could push it instead of reassigning it:

if your observable array is `self.displayedData` then, in your ajax success, instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.displayedData)` you could do something like

```
$(data).each(function(i,e){
  self.displayedData.push(ko.mapping.toJS(e));
});
```